# XMLHttpRequest from my https site to an external http thesaurus API

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xmlhttprequest

I want to make an XMLHttpRequest from my https site to an external http thesaurus API:

```
...
var myWord = "test";
...
xhr.open(
    "GET",
    "http://somethesaurus.com/service.php?word=" + myWord + "&callback=process",
    true
);
```

however Chrome warns:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.myownsite.com' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://somethesaurus.com/service.php?word=test&callback=process'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I know that:

- my site has https
- the requested site allows cross origin requests
- the requested site has no https
- it works on the regular http version of my site (http to http)
- I can use mod-rewrite on my host sever and can redirect one html file
  to another

I'm looking for a proxy script or some kind of htaccess code that can allow me to access the http site from my https site.

for example, I tried with http://benalman.com/code/projects/php-simple-proxy/examples/simple/ but I had no luck with it. E.g.

```
...
"https://myownsite.com/php-simple-proxy.php?url=http://somethesaurus.com/service.php?word=" + myWord + "&callback=process",
...
```

Any help most appreciated, thanks.